# Is it possible to connect pivot table cells to data using pandas once the file has been saved?

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have successfully written a script that takes two files, filters out for the correct data, and creates a pivot table of the data. However, I want the end file to have the same functionality as an Excel file PivotTable. For example, you can add extra columns/rows, right click to filter, or click on cells to bring up all matching rows from the data. Is it possible to do this using Pandas? Here is my code script, which isolates all the data and creates the visual look of the PivotTable, but not the actual functionality of one. Thanks!

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date

today = date.today()
d1 = today.strftime('%m.%d.%Y')

excel1 = 'lookupfile.xlsx'
excel2 = 'mainfile.xlsx'
new_file = 'newfile ' + d1 +'.xlsx'
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(new_file, engine='xlsxwriter')


cutoff_date = '2019-09-23'
ref_num = 'REFERENCE NUMBER'
gnc = 'DISPLAY CODE'
obooked_date = 'ORIGINAL BOOKED DATE'
rep_name = 'REPRESENTATIVE NAME'

#Delete top 3 junk rows of Excel File and last two summary rows
df1 = pd.read_excel(excel1, header=3)
df1 = (df1[:-2])

df2 = pd.read_excel(excel2)

#finds all ref numbers that have the ESBK code
has_gnc = df1[(df1[gnc] == 'ESBK022') | (df1[gnc] == 'ESBK023')
              | (df1[gnc] == 'ESBK024')]

#does a vlookup
lookup_table = df2.loc[~df2[ref_num].isin(has_gnc[ref_num])]

#removes everything that's before the cutoff date
lookup_table = lookup_table[pd.to_datetime(lookup_table[obooked_date]) >= cutoff_date]

#creates Pivot Table layout
df3 = lookup_table.pivot_table(index=rep_name, columns=obooked_date, aggfunc ='count', values=ref_num, margins='True')
df3 = df3.iloc[:-1]


#saves File
df3.to_excel(writer,sheet_name='PIVOT', index=True)
lookup_table.to_excel(writer,sheet_name='DATA', index=False)

writer.save()
```

Comment: Is this something you are looking for https://pbpython.com/pandas-pivot-report.html

If you want to save the data like a excel pivot, where you can click on the pivot are in the excel sheet and on the right side the Pivot User interface opens where you can do stuff, this is not possible with pandas. You can - as you did - create pivots with python pandas and then save the results as an excel sheet.

Comment: I came across this earlier and was hoping it's not the only option. I was hoping to just completely copy the pivot table exactly? Is there anyway to do this outside of pandas? I guess I could write a VBA macro and just use my script to run that file.

Comment: python pandas is not the desired tool to to that. As mentioned, what you can expect from it, is to save your python pandas output as a excel file. If you really want to have pivot table as you know from excel, where you can add elements, drag drop etc. it's not possible. At least I dont know it :)